# how to set cache control in laravel

Tags: laravel, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm setting the background image for a page with css in blade template

```
background: url('img/background.png');
```

and in .htaccess file I added this:

```
<Files "background.png">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=300, private"
</Files>
```

I'm expecting that the server would set the cache control header for the file background.png but it does not.

How can I set the Cache-Control header for "background.png" ?

Comment: I think the directive name is `<Files`

Comment: I changed it but still not working

Comment: this has nothing to do with laravel. this is an Apache question from the looks of it.